# Configure containerd to use the registry certificate for kubernetes/kubespray

Tags: linux, kubernetes, ssl-certificate

No much experience in kubernetes.

I had a task assigned to Configure containerd to use the registry certificate for kubernetes/kubespray.

I've done several searches but can't find anything similar.

In days gone by, I implemented a solution to go from a private registry repo to a secure registry. Executed configurations and startup of private registry and secure access from worker nodes (using the x509 certificates and key). Even when this design was exposed, none of this was part of the solution.

Only required to Configure containerd to use the registry certificate for kubernetes/kubespray. I don't know how to do it

I was taking a look over this :https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/main/docs/hosts.md.

I want to know what modifications should occur; in what files if for example in config.toml, ?